# Ubuntu on Mac / Parallels, screen resolution

Tags: display, laptop, screen, display-resolution, parallels

I have just downloaded Ubuntu onto my mac using parallels. The only issue is that the Ubuntu window is about an inch too small each side. I have checked the display settings and the only display setting I can choose is 800x600(4:3). I have attempted to change this using:

Change screen resolution:

Create a new resolution using `cvt`:

```
$ cvt 1600 900 75
1600x900 74.89 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 70.55 kHz; pclk: 151.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_75.00" 151.25 1600 1704 1872 2144 900 903 908 942 -hsync +vsync
```

Add a new mode to the existing list (newmode is the name and remaining portion is):

```
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_75.00" 151.25 1600 1704 1872 2144 900 903 908 942 -hsync +vsync
```

but once I enter the newmode an error message pops up saying "failed to get size of gamma output default".

I am trying to get this working on my laptop not a monitor.